# Issue with writing script autosave Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm currently learning lua/roblox scripting and whenever I open my project I get a message in my terminal that says "Issue writing script autosave" and whenever I edit my code the message multiplies.
I haven't encountered anything strange happening after that message but im just concerned on what it means and how to get rid of it.

I try searching it up on the roblox studio developer forums but can't find anything, a link to a forum about my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Shot in the dark, how is your computer doing on hard drive space?

Comment: My computer’s pretty fine on space, it shouldn’t be an issue.